# Deep power down mode in LPC17xx

Tags: low-power, lpc

I am currently working on a home project. I want to put my LPC1769 in deep power down mode. this is the code I have so far:

```
SCR |= (1 << SLEEPDEEP); 
PCON |= (1 << PM1);
```

It doesn't work, I don't know why. I read something about __WFI() and __WFE(), I tried to implement this, but the following error appeared:

> __WFI was not declared in this scope

Can someone help to to put my LPC1769 in deep power down mode?

Answer (score 1):

Yes - after configuring the power/sleep mode you have to issue a WFE or WFI instruction to make the MCU enter the desired sleep mode.

You are not including CMSIS headers (eg. `cmsis_gcc.h` or another, it probably has to be included via another file like `core_cm3.h`).

You can also simply use:

```
asm("wfe");
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I added asm("wfi") and it worked!